# how to use javascript to extract chinese characters from the url?

Tags: javascript, url, encode

I want to use javascript to extract chinese characters from the web url which contains parameters as percent-and-hex encoded? maybe it is about encoding and decoding...Can anybody tell me a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for `decodeURIComponent`

```
decodeURIComponent("%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87");
```

output

```
"中文"
```